# Using Async-Await for API onload

Tags: javascript, async-await

I've been working on this little hangman game project.

I added an api to grab an array of random words, but the array is not loading when I call it outside the `request.onload`. The function `displayWord()` is outside `request.onload` and uses `apiArr`. When I `console.log(apiArr)` it is empty because it is not waiting for the api to get the data for the array.

I figured I can just move everything inside the request.onload, but I felt like that would look messy.

Is there a way to use async-await to so it can wait for the onload and look clean?

The code snippet below will not run since this is just some partial code and I don't want to put the api key public, but I hope it helps with the concept.

```js
let apiArr= [];

//making a request to get word array
let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', apiURL);
request.responseType = 'json';
request.send();

request.onload = function() {
  const wordArr = request.response;
  //taking the word array and adding each word to the empty apiArr. 
  for(let i = 0; i < wordArr.length; i++) {
    let newWordArr = wordArr[i].word;
    console.log(newWordArr);
    apiArr.push(newWordArr);   
}
}

//If I try to use the apiArr anywhere other than inside the request.onload, the array loads as an empty array instead of waiting for the resquest to fill it out. 

//I have a function called displayWord that uses apiArr ( i did not put the whole this b/c its long.

// How can I make it so it waits for the api request using async/await?


displayWord();
```

Comment: With [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) you can do `apiArr = await fetch(apiURL).then(r => r.json());` inside an async function, then simply call `displayWord()`. That's because you don't have to move *everything* into the function, just the stuff that happens after the page load.

Comment: Where is `displayWord()` defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `displayWord` needs `appArr`, consider making it an `async` function and using the `fetch` API to make the request. So it should look something like this.

```js
async function displayWord() {
  let appArr;
  try {
     appArr = await fetch(apiURL).then(res => res.json());
     // do stuff with your  appArr here
  } catch(err) {
    console.error(err)
  }
}

displayWord();
```

I'm wrapping it in a `try/catch` block, just so if your request fails you can see the errors in the console

Comment: Thanks for your help on this!